# How am I suppose to stub a function which is dependent on result of previous function?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, tdd, sinon, chai

I have recently started writing tests and I don't have much experience.If any of the community member could point me in the right direction I would be really thankful. My scenario is simple I am half way through it but unable to solve my exact problem. Below is my code..

```
return generateServiceToken(req.body.appId, req.body.token, req.auth.userId)
  .then(result => {
    someService
      .createCredentialsForUser(
        req.auth.userId,
        result.user.uid,
        result.user.token
      )
      .then(result => {
        return res.status(201).send(result);
      });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return res.status(500).send({ error: `Credentials not valid - ${error}` });
  });
```

The generateToken function is responsible to call a third party api to generate some credentials for their platform and return us the create credentials.

```
function generateServiceToken(appId: String, token: String, userId: String) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject)=>{
    const apiURL = `https://someapi.com/api/api.php?op=useradd&token=${token}&addr=${userId}&appid=${appId}`;
    request.post(apiURL, (error, response, body) => {
        const resp = JSON.parse(body);
        if (resp.error) return reject(resp.error);

        return resolve(resp);
    });
  });
}
```

Whereas, the someService.createCredentialsForUser function is responsible to save those credentials in database and return back the result in simple json format.

I am just stuck in stubbing someService.createCredentialsForUser function while writing the test case for happy-path

My test case is below..

```
describe.only("controllers/v3/some/", () => {
  const c = {};

  before(() => {
    c.sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

    c.someServiceStub = c.sandbox
      .stub(someService, "createCredentialsForUser")
      .resolves(VALID_OUTPUT);
  });

  describe("when the request is valid", () => {
    before(() => {
      c.agent = setupApp(authenticationMiddleware(USER_ID));
      return test(c, VALID_REQUEST_BODY);
    });

    it("should return 201", () => {
      expect(c.response.statusCode).to.equal(201);
    });

    it("should call createCredentialsForUser", () => {
      expect(c.stubs.createCredentialsForUser.called).to.equal(true);
    });
  });
});
```

The TestCase function is as follows..

```
function testCase(context, body = VALID_REQUEST_BODY) {
  context.sandbox.resetHistory();
  console.log(body.length);
  const c = context;
  return context.agent
    .put(`/v3/some/`)
    .send(body)
    .then(r => {
      c.response = r;
    });
  //.catch(err=>{c.response=err});
}
```

My someService.createCredentialsForUser function is responsible to save data into database I want to stub that that in a way that I could expect response return from generateServiceToken

I tried couples of ways which are as follows ..

First, I tried to stub that function in before() but no luck it fails with

```
 error : IllegalArgumentError: init() must be called prior to use.
```

Second, I tried

```
 c.response = c.sandbox.stub(someService, 'createCredentialsForUser').returns(Promise.resolve(r));
```

in my test function to stub with the value of resolved promise but no luck in this case it fails with the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: can you paste `someService` code? is it a class or function?

Comment: it is saving object to database that is why I am stubbing it atm I am just interested in testing the happy-path

Comment: @MQ. were you able to find a solution in the meantime? I am stuck at a similar problem and a hint / answer would be very helpful

Comment: @hajn I was using request-promise(npm module) to make a api call and I was not stubbing it. I solved it by stubbing it.